# Most idiomatic way of creating custom events in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What is the most idiomatic way of creating a non-DOM-related custom event (with the classic `chrome.Event` interface) and manually store it and trigger it?

I have an object `obj` in my program on which I want to create few event objects such as `obj.event1` and `obj.event2` such that:

```
obj.event1.addListener(callback);
obj.event2.removeListener(callback);
...
```

are valid calls.

I know it's fairly easy to implement it on your own, but I was wondering if there's a better way. Thanks.

Personal research:

- [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events): are created for and from the `document` object
- [`chrome.events`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/events#type-Event): displays the interface without explaining how to create custom events
- [Chrome events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events): it does show how to add rules to existing events, but not how to create your own custom events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`chrome.Event`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events) cannot be used for custom events.

To trigger custom events without libraries, standard DOM events can be used as follows:

```
var listener = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.detail);
};

var target = document.createElement('a'); // Anything that implements EventTarget
target.addEventListener('myEvent', listener);
target.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myEvent', {
    detail: 'test',
}));
```

As you can see, there is no need for registering all events on `document`, it is very well possible to use any object that implements the [`EventTarget` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). This will work even if you are trying to trigger an event from one part of your extension (e.g. a popup) to be handled in another (e.g. a background page):

Wherever you want to receive messages, register an event handler:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
  if (!(event in message)) {
    return;
  }
  if (message.event == "sayHello") {
    console.log("Hello!");
  }
});
```

Then you can trigger the handler like so from any other part of your extension:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({event: "sayHello"});
```